# Spring Security: Deny access to controller methods, if @PreAuthorize annotation is missing

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a web application configured to use Spring Security 3.2 in standard way.

I'm using the `@PreAuthorize` annotation to secure the Controllers method.
Now, I would like to **deny** access to each controller method **UNLESS** it is annotated with `@PreAuthorize`.

I have tried the following approaches:

**super controller**

Each controller extends from a super controller annotated with: `@PreAutorize("denyAll")`. This approach doesn't seem to work because the controllers' methods annotations are ignored. Everything is forbidden.

```
@PreAutorize("denyAll") 
public class SuperController {

}

public class MyController extends SuperController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('SUPERHERO')")
    @RequestMapping(value = URL_PREFIX + "Add.do", method =  RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doStuff(Model model) {

        ...
    }

}
```

**aop**

Using a pointcut expression in the global method security tag

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* com.acme.*Controller.*(..))" access="denyAll" />
 </global-method-security>
```

This approach also fails: controllers's methods which are not annotated are still accessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here.

I've solved the problem by using a [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html).

I'm not sure it is the most Spring-idiomatic way to achieve the result, but it's good enough for me.

```
public class MvcPreAuthorizeAnnotationCheckerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    final HandlerMethod hm;
    if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
        hm = (HandlerMethod) handler;
        PreAuthorize annotation = hm.getMethodAnnotation(PreAuthorize.class);
        if (annotation == null) {
            // check if the class is annotated...
            annotation = hm.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getAnnotation(PreAuthorize.class);
            if (annotation == null) {
                // add logging
                // or send a NON AUTHORIZED
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
            }
       }
       return true;
    }
}
```

And in the Spring config:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <beans:ref bean="mvcPreAuthorizeAnnotationCheckerInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>

<beans:bean id="mvcPreAuthorizeAnnotationCheckerInterceptor" class="com.acme.MvcPreAuthorizeAnnotationCheckerInterceptor"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a similar approach, but its not executed for every request but just extends the `ConfigAttribute`'s for the method:

A minor drawback could be that it does not allow for easy logging or whatever the big benefit is that it follows the same deny behavior as other not allowed endpoints.

**SecurityConfig**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityMetadataSource customMethodSecurityMetadataSource() {
        return new CustomPermissionAllowedMethodSecurityMetadataSource();
    }
}
```

**MetadataSource**:

```java
public class CustomPermissionAllowedMethodSecurityMetadataSource extends AbstractFallbackMethodSecurityMetadataSource {
    @Override
    protected Collection<ConfigAttribute> findAttributes(Class<?> clazz) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Collection<ConfigAttribute> findAttributes(Method method, Class<?> targetClass) {
        Annotation[] annotations = AnnotationUtils.getAnnotations(method);
        List<ConfigAttribute> attributes = new ArrayList<>();

        // if the class itself is annotated as a @Controller we should by default deny access to every method
        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(targetClass, Controller.class) != null) {
            attributes.add(DENY_ALL_ATTRIBUTE);
        }

        if (annotations != null) {
            for (Annotation a : annotations) {
                // but not if the method has at least a PreAuthorize or PostAuthorize annotation
                if (a instanceof PreAuthorize || a instanceof PostAuthorize) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        return attributes;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I also wrote a small article about this, with some further background: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deny-access

Comment: Martin van Wingerden: Thank you for your tutorial on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deny-access Can i change the response code of an controller without @PreAuthorize from 200 to 403?

Comment: @Ben thanks for your message, I just checked my Baeldung code and it correctly responds with a 401 if there is no authentication. And 403 when there is authentication. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I am using your approach in combination with an oauth2-resource-server and a custom BearerTokenResolver to support a custom 'Authentication' header. When I comment out the BearerTokenResolver bean, the response is 401. When I use the BearerTokenResolver bean, the response is 200. Unfortunately, I don't understand how this dependency comes about. Do you perhaps have an idea?

Comment: I suppose something is off with your `BearerTokenResolver` maybe we can take it elsewhere via email, feel free to reach out to me, eg via my Dutch website, https://martinvw.nl/#contact